# Redirecting visitors after two java timer rotations

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cookies

This sounds strange I know. Basically I have a page that redirects users after 30 seconds. It's going to be used as a VPN/PROXY warning page. It basically shows the users IP tells them why they have been denied from accessing my website. I mention previously that It has a 30 second timer that redirects the user using javascript.

Count.js

```
// count.js

function init() {
    var n = 30;
    e = document.getElementById("output");
    setInterval(function() { e.innerHTML = --n; }, 1000);
}

window.onload =init;
```

I have this running next to a HTML timer on the page itself.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=denied.html">
```

This shows a timer that counts down by 1 second every tick and at the end redirects the user back to "denied.html" to reload the page (This is just a placeholder for testing purposes).

I want to create a cookie or something that detects after 2 attempts to reload the website it will redirect the person back to there browser homepage or google.

30 seconds - Attempt to reconnect back to website. (fails) Redirects back to denied.html

30 seconds - Attempts to reconnect back to website. (fails a second time) redirects back to browser home page or google.

I want to have a feature like that to prevent people from just using those page to constantly create load on my server. Aka redirecting back and forth in an infinite loop. (like the Looper movie if you will).

Only issue I see in using cookies is people can just disable cookies and then use this method so I'm not sure what to do.

This is a little bit of an odd request. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will find a satisfactory solution using client-side code.  As you say, people can turn off javascript, and any automated attack is unlikely to execute javascript.

Look into something server-side such as PHP Sessions to achieve what you want.

(If you are not self-hosting, then your hosting company may have methods alrady in place to prevent Denial-of-service attacks. Depending on your reasons for wanting this in place, they may be able to advise a more sensible solution)

Comment: I want it mainly prevent unnecessary load on the server I doubtful that it could DDoS unless a ridiculous amount of people were doing it at the same time. Which I guess is possible but they would all need to be running through a proxy or VPN for that to even be possible.